# How can I list all records which belong to another record at the show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a table of venues and a table of areas, where a venue belongs to an area and an area has many venues.

How can I show all the venues which belong to an area when I view the areas show page?

I thought this would work:

**area show.html.erb:**

```
<%= area.venue.name %>, or
<%= area.venue.name, :collection => @area.venues %>
```

**routes:**

```
resources :areas, :has_many => :venues
```

but it gives an "undefined local variable or method `area'" error or a syntax error.

I'm super new to any programming and rails what am I doing wrong?

Also, I have a venue partial set up but it's being displayed in another part of my app, I would just like the venue names listed without using partials.

Thanks very much for any help its much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, can you show us your `areas_controller.rb` file please?

Inside your view you can do this by doing:

```
<% @area.venues.each do |venue| %>
  <%= venue.name %>
  # etc.
<% end %>
```

This implies that inside your areas controller, you have a `show` action that instantiates the @area instance variable.

Something like:

```
def show
  @area = Area.find(params[:id])
end
```

And by the way, don't put your model relations inside the routes.rb file! You need to put them inside your models.

Area.rb

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
end
```

Venue.rb

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area
end
```